# Hyperlink not working within CiviCRM emails

Tags: email

When I send an email on CiviCRM, and want to add a hyperlink (to a webpage for example), I've had responses from those I sent it to that the link doesn't work. I've followed the hyperlink button on the formatting tab above on emails so would like to know if there is anything else I should be doing. Thanks

Comment: welcome Sarah. what are you seeing in the tests that you are sending to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

CiviMail is usually (and by default) configured to mangle the links in a civimail message in order to be able to track them. I suspect you've got a configuration issue which is preventing those mangled urls from working properly.

A mangled url typically looks something like this:

https://example.org/civicrm/mailing/url?u=21189&qid=1478417

Solutions:

1. If you're in a hurry, you can just turn off the link tracking for your message.
2. CiviCRM has recently converted from a different url for such purpose (one with "extern" in the path) - if you've got an old link like that which is breaking, you probably want to update your civicrm version to fix the problem.

In any case, to help you further, it'd be useful to get details about the link that "doesn't work", i.e. provide the url of an example and also what you're seeing on the screen when following that url.